# Select the next data cell given a data cell with Playwright

Tags: selector, playwright

There are several tables on a page.  I'm. trying to get City/Town.

```
<table class="table" style="margin-top: 35px;">
                    <thead>
                        <!--<tr>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>-->
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Street</td>
                            <td>61 Essex St</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>City/Town</td>
                            <td>Lynn</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>State/Province/Region</td>
                            <td>Maine</td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td>Zip/Postal Code</td>
                            <td>01902</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I know I can get the element for the cell item above what I need.

```
let foo = page.locator(`test=City/Town`)
```

but I'm not sure how to get the next data cell.  I googled and tried:

```
let foo = page.locator(`td:below(:text("street"))`).innerText()
```

but that didn't work.  I also tried:

```
let foo = page.locator(`td:near(:text'("Street"))+td`).first().textContent()
```

this didn't work for me either.   I tried some other variations.
Can you help a clueless man out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator): `page.locator('td:text("City/Town") + td')`.

Example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // 1.23.3

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<table class="table" style="margin-top: 35px;">
  <thead>
    <!--<tr>
    <th scope="col"></th>
    <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>-->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Street</td>
      <td>61 Essex St</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City/Town</td>
      <td>Lynn</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>State/Province/Region</td>
      <td>Maine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zip/Postal Code</td>
      <td>01902</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);

  const result = await page.locator('td:text("City/Town") + td')
    .textContent();
  console.log(result); // => Lynn
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```